# Suma de arreglos unidimensionales

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

        int [] aa = new int [5];
        int [] bb = new int [5];
        int [] ss = new int [5];
        int i;

        for (i=0; i<aa.length; i++);{
            System.out.print("Ingrese elemento i del arreglo a: ");
            aa [i] = teclado.nextInt();
        }   
        for (i=0; i<bb.length; i++);{   
            System.out.print("Ingrese elemento i del arreglo b: ");
            bb [i] = teclado.nextInt();

        ss[i]=(aa[i]+bb[i]);
        }   

        System.out.print("La suma es");
        for (i=0; i<=4; i++);{
            System.out.println(aa[i]);
            System.out.println(bb[i]);
            System.out.println(ss[i]);
        }   

    }

}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at Main.main(Main.java:13) Esto me sale al momento de querer ingresar mi segundo numero, lo que quiero es ingresar valores a los dos arreglor y sumarlos y que las respuestas se vean en un tercer arreglo si me pueden ayudar por favor. aa [i] = teclado.nextInt(); aqui exactamente sale que existe un error(Main.java:13)

Comment: Un simple error de dedo y lo copiaste, solo elimina el  ";"  de los for, de  tal manera que quede así :     for (i=0; i<aa.length; i++){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error en realidad se debe a esto:

```
for (i=0; i<aa.length; i++);{
```

Estas colocando **;** en la sentencia del for, lo cual finaliza el recorrido de dicho for en la "primer vuelta".

Lo correcto seria:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] aa = new int[5];
    int[] bb = new int[5];
    int[] ss = new int[5];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Ingrese elemento i del arreglo a: ");
        aa[i] = teclado.nextInt();
    }
    for (i = 0; i < bb.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Ingrese elemento i del arreglo b: ");
        bb[i] = teclado.nextInt();

        ss[i] = (aa[i] + bb[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Las sumas son: ");
    for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        System.out.println(aa[i] + " + " + bb[i] + " = " + ss[i]);

    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias compa no me habia fijado en ese pequeño gran error

Comment: De nada! Suele pasar.

Answer (score -1):

Creo que tienes un ";" de mas en las lineas del for.

```
for (i=0; i<aa.length; i++);
```

Un saludo!

Comment: Estas en la versión en Español de Stack Overflow. Traduce tu respuesta.

Comment: Por favor traduce tu respuesta, estas en SO en español y por tanto las publicaciones son en español